# Microsoft SQL Server: error converting varchar to numeric - try_cast succeeded -CLOSED

Tags: sql-server

The code below returns an error converting data type `varchar` to `numeric`. Value_2,a string, failed to be converted to a decimal number.

```
update #table
set value = cast(value_2 as decimal(18, 2))
where value is null and value_2 is not null;
```

I then used `try_cast` to see if I can parse values through successfully.

```
select case
    when try_cast(value_2 as decimal(18, 2)) is null
    then 'cast failed'
    else 'cast succeeded'
    end as result
from #table;
```

Every value that was parsed through came back as "cast succeeded".

Therefore, I don't know why the cast function in my previous code returned that error of converting data type `varchar` to `numeric`.

A data sample of the variable value_2 is like this:

```
value_2
-------
35.5
30.2
26.0
13
16
```

Comment: What's the value that failed? NULL?

Comment: It's weird that try_cast never returned a NULL when cast did, however if try_cast is successfully casting all values then just replace cast with try_cast.

Comment: It might help to see some data samples.

Comment: show us your table definition and data

Comment: Just out of interest, could you run `SELECT * FROM #table WHERE try_cast(value_2 as decimal(18, 2)) IS NULL AND value_2 IS NOT NULL;` and see if you get any results? If you do the problem lies with those rows. If you don't, then maybe there's part of the query that we're not seeing that is causing an issue (as in something you've left out of your question)?

Comment: Are you sure it's cast that's failing...or can it be Update to value that's might be an issue?? select cast(value_2 as decimal(18, 2)) from #table
where value is null and value_2 is not null gives you error too??

Comment: Yes! I tried `select * from #table where try_cast(value_2 as decimal(18,2)) is null and value_2 is not null;` and it returned one row. I see that `value` has a decimal after the last digit, which is the reason why `cast` didn't work. Thank you so much @zlk and @raska !